# How to fix this nav while on responsive mode?

Tags: html, css

I have been working on this site, but have a big problem. I can't seem to put a color in my navbar while on responsive mode. The logo and hamburger overlaps with the content on the page.

Any help will be appreciated!

Codepen link:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VJdEpx

Sc of problem:
https://gyazo.com/1627135953ad0149d4c51d7d8837aef7

Tried using a new id or class to put color, but no luck!

--- Media query---

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
.logo {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            margin-top: 12px;
            margin-left: -8px;
      }
      .logo a {
        text-indent: -9999px;
      }

      .nav-wrapper {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
            background: #fff;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            width: 100%;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li {
            display: block;
            float: none;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: right;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(1) a {
            transition-delay: 0.2s;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(2) a {
            transition-delay: 0.3s;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(3) a {
            transition-delay: 0.4s;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(4) a {
            transition-delay: 0.5s;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:not(:first-child) {
            margin-left: 0;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li a {
            padding: 10px 50px;
            opacity: 0;
            color: #000;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 600;
            letter-spacing: 1.2px;
            transform: translateX(-20px);
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
      }

      .nav-btn {
            position: fixed;
            right: 10px;
            top: 10px;
            display: block;
            width: 48px;
            height: 48px;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 9999;
            border-radius: 50%;
      }

      .nav-btn i {
            display: block;
            width: 20px;
            height: 2px;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 2px;
            margin-left: 14px;
      }

      .nav-btn i:nth-child(1) {
            margin-top: 16px;
      }

      .nav-btn i:nth-child(2) {
            margin-top: 4px;
            opacity: 1;
      }

      .nav-btn i:nth-child(3) {
            margin-top: 4px;
      }

#nav:checked + .nav-btn {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav:checked + .nav-btn i {
      background: #000;
      transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

#nav:checked + .nav-btn i:nth-child(1) {
      transform: translateY(6px) rotate(180deg);
}

#nav:checked + .nav-btn i:nth-child(2) {
      opacity: 0;
}

#nav:checked + .nav-btn i:nth-child(3) {
      transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(90deg);
}

#nav:checked ~ .nav-wrapper {
      z-index: 9990;
      opacity: 1;
}

#nav:checked ~ .nav-wrapper ul li a {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0);
}

    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you try for `BOOTSTAP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this media query to your code.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav {
    height: 48px;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .logo a {
    text-indent: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: DINPro;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background-image: url(../hero-background.jpg);
  background-color: black;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px
}

.container .button {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.container .button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/* Slider */

#section-b {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}


/* Nav bar */

nav {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(../prftab-01.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
}

.logo a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 55px;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 48px;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 24px;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  font-weight: 600;
  z-index: 1;
}


/*Navbar finish*/

.cursos {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: initial;
}

.cursos:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/*Certificaciones*/

#section-a ul {
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  text-align: center;
}

#section-a li {
  list-style: none;
}


/*cuerpo de la pagina*/

.content {
  text-align: center;
}

.content h1 {
  color: #f7971e;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.content p {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.features {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}

.feature {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}

.feature-contnt h2 {
  color: #f7971e;
}

.icon {
  padding: 23px 10px;
}

.feature-contnt2 h2 {
  color: #2d2d2d;
}

.feature-contnt2 p {
  color: #2d2d2d;
}


/*preguntas texto */

.feature-a {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 23px;
}

.features-a {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  padding: 23px;
}


/*preguntas frecuentes */

.preguntas {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
}

.preguntas h1 {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.preguntas p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
}


/* clase */

.clase {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 70px 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.clase h1 {
  color: #707070;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.clase p {
  color: #2d2d2d;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

.clase .btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4a00e0;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 60px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.clase .btn:hover {
  background-color: #4a00e0;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.clase .btn2:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #4a00e0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.clase .btn2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-color: #4a00e0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.botones {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  .logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: -8px;
  }
  .logo a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
  }
  .cursos {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .nav-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
  }
  .nav-wrapper ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav-wrapper ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(1) a {
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
  }
  .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(2) a {
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
  }
  .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(3) a {
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
  }
  .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(4) a {
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
  }
  .nav-wrapper ul li:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .nav-wrapper ul li a {
    padding: 10px 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    transform: translateX(-20px);
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
  }
  .nav-btn {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 9999;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  .nav-btn i {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-left: 14px;
  }
  .nav-btn i:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
  .nav-btn i:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 4px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .nav-btn i:nth-child(3) {
    margin-top: 4px;
  }
  /*container header */
  .wrapper {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .container h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .container p {
    font-size: 19px;
  }
  #section-a ul {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  }
  .features-a {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, auto);
  }
  .features {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, auto);
  }
  .botones {
    display: grid;
  }
  .clase .btn {
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  .clase .btn2 {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .features {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .features-a {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .feature-contnt2 h2 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .feature-contnt2 p {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .feature-a {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
}

#nav:checked+.nav-btn {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav:checked+.nav-btn i {
  background: #000;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

#nav:checked+.nav-btn i:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(6px) rotate(180deg);
}

#nav:checked+.nav-btn i:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#nav:checked+.nav-btn i:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(90deg);
}

#nav:checked~.nav-wrapper {
  z-index: 9990;
  opacity: 1;
}

#nav:checked~.nav-wrapper ul li a {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav {
    height: 48px;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .logo a {
    text-indent: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Puerto Rico & Florida Recovery Training Academy</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav" class="hidden">
      <label for="nav" class="nav-btn">
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
          </label>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">PRFTA</a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="cursos">Cursos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Puerto Rico & Florida Recovery Training Academy</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae doloremque autem nam, illo nisi soluta voluptatibus et in fugiat aliquid nostrum asperiores. Laboriosam vitae, minus odio! Iure id quaerat voluptatum.</p>
        <a href="#section-a" class="button">MAS INFORMACIÓN</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section id="section-a">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><img src="prueba.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="prueba.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="prueba.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="prueba.png" alt=""></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="content">
        <h1>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur error deserunt saepe explicabo obcaecati cupiditate dolor quam, nisi illo! Soluta.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="features">
        <div class="feature">
          <i class="fa fa-gear icon"></i>
          <div class="feature-contnt">
            <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature">
          <i class="fa fa-gear icon"></i>
          <div class="feature-contnt">
            <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Features Two. -->
      <div class="features">
        <div class="feature">
          <i class="fa fa-gear icon"></i>
          <div class="feature-contnt">
            <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature">
          <i class="fa fa-gear icon"></i>
          <div class="feature-contnt">
            <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Slider. -->

  <!-- Preguntas -->
  <section id="section-b">
    <div class="preguntas">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Preguntas frecuentes</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit laboriosam repellat labore, ad qui assumenda. Beatae perferendis at, provident aspernatur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Preguntas 2 en flex -->
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="features-a">
        <div class="feature-a">
          <div class="feature-contnt2">
            <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-a">
          <div class="feature-contnt2">
            <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Preguntas 2-4 en flex -->
      <div class="features-a">
        <div class="feature-a">
          <div class="feature-contnt2">
            <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-a">
          <div class="feature-contnt2">
            <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Preguntas 4-6 en flex -->
      <div class="features-a">
        <div class="feature-a">
          <div class="feature-contnt2">
            <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-a">
          <div class="feature-contnt2">
            <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <!-- Curso -->
    <div class="clase">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>¿Listos para comenzar?</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium possimus officia, consequuntur repellat natus voluptatibus ad explicabo architecto! Quos, saepe!</p>
        <div class="botones">
          <a href="#section-a" class="btn">PRESENCIAL</a>
          <a href="#section-a" class="btn2">EN LINEA</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Irin, you fixed a problem that I was figuring out all day. I still have to a lot to learn about css!

Comment: you are wc please accepte this answer as an accepted answer and give me a vote. moreover its all about practice css. follow https://css-tricks.com/ and w3 school to learn css. best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do:

```css
      html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: DINPro;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  background-image: url(../hero-background.jpg);
  background-color: black;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.container p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px
}
.container .button {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
.container .button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
/* Slider */
#section-b {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Nav bar */
nav {
      padding: 10px 20px;
      z-index: -1;
}

.logo {
      float: left;
      padding: 8px;
      margin-left: 16px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-image: url(../prftab-01.svg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      z-index: 1;
}

.logo a {
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 20px;
      letter-spacing: 0px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 55px;
      z-index: 1;
}

nav ul {
      float: right;
      z-index: 1;
}

nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      z-index: 1;
}

nav ul li:not(:first-child) {
      margin-left: 48px;
      z-index: 1;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
      margin-right: 24px;
      z-index: 1;
}

nav ul li a {
      display: inline-block;
      outline: none;
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      letter-spacing: 1.2px;
      font-weight: 600;
      z-index: 1;
}

/*Navbar finish*/

.cursos {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: initial;
}
.cursos:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/*Certificaciones*/
#section-a ul {
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  text-align: center;
}

#section-a li {
  list-style: none;
}

/*cuerpo de la pagina*/
.content {
  text-align: center;
}
.content h1 {
  color: #f7971e;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.content p {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.features {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
.feature {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}
.feature-contnt h2 {
  color: #f7971e;
}
.icon {
  padding: 23px 10px;
}

.feature-contnt2 h2 {
  color: #2d2d2d;
}
.feature-contnt2 p {
  color: #2d2d2d;
}
/*preguntas texto */
.feature-a {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 23px;
}
.features-a {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  padding: 23px;
}
/*preguntas frecuentes */
.preguntas {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
}
.preguntas h1 {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.preguntas p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

/* clase */
.clase {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 70px 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.clase h1 {
  color: #707070;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.clase p {
  color: #2d2d2d;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
.clase .btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4a00e0;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 60px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.clase .btn:hover {
  background-color: #4a00e0;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.clase .btn2:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #4a00e0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.clase .btn2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-color: #4a00e0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.botones {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    nav{
        background:brown;
        padding:34px 20px;
        position:fixed;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
      slider {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        margin-top: 50px;
      }

      .logo {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            margin-top: 12px;
            margin-left: -8p
      }
      .logo a {
        margin-left:0;
      }
      .cursos {
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .nav-wrapper {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
            background: #fff;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            width: 100%;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li {
            display: block;
            float: none;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: right;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(1) a {
            transition-delay: 0.2s;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(2) a {
            transition-delay: 0.3s;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(3) a {
            transition-delay: 0.4s;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(4) a {
            transition-delay: 0.5s;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:not(:first-child) {
            margin-left: 0;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li a {
            padding: 10px 50px;
            opacity: 0;
            color: #000;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 600;
            letter-spacing: 1.2px;
            transform: translateX(-20px);
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
      }

      .nav-btn {
            position: fixed;
            right: 10px;
            top: 10px;
            display: block;
            width: 48px;
            height: 48px;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 9999;
            border-radius: 50%;
      }

      .nav-btn i {
            display: block;
            width: 20px;
            height: 2px;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 2px;
            margin-left: 14px;
      }

      .nav-btn i:nth-child(1) {
            margin-top: 16px;
      }

      .nav-btn i:nth-child(2) {
            margin-top: 4px;
            opacity: 1;
      }

      .nav-btn i:nth-child(3) {
            margin-top: 4px;
      }
/*container header */
      .wrapper {
        width: 90%;
      }

      .container h1 {
        font-size: 24px;
      }
      .container p {
        font-size: 19px;
      }
      #section-a ul {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
      }
      .features-a {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, auto);
      }
      .features {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, auto);
      }
      .botones {
        display: grid;
      }
      .clase .btn {
        margin-right: 30px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
      }
      .clase .btn2 {
        margin-left: 20px;
      }
      .features {
        padding: 0;
      }
      .features-a {
        padding-bottom: 0px;
      }
      .feature-contnt2 h2 {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .feature-contnt2 p {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .feature-a {
        padding-left: 0px;
      }
}

#nav:checked + .nav-btn {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav:checked + .nav-btn i {
      background: #000;
      transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

#nav:checked + .nav-btn i:nth-child(1) {
      transform: translateY(6px) rotate(180deg);
}

#nav:checked + .nav-btn i:nth-child(2) {
      opacity: 0;
}

#nav:checked + .nav-btn i:nth-child(3) {
      transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(90deg);
}

#nav:checked ~ .nav-wrapper {
      z-index: 9990;
      opacity: 1;
}

#nav:checked ~ .nav-wrapper ul li a {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0);
}

.hidden {
      display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Puerto Rico & Florida Recovery Training Academy</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
        <nav>
          <input type="checkbox" id="nav" class="hidden">
          <label for="nav" class="nav-btn">
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
          </label>
          <div class="logo">
              <a href="#">PRFTA</a>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-wrapper">
              <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="cursos">Cursos</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Puerto Rico & Florida Recovery Training Academy</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae doloremque autem nam, illo nisi soluta voluptatibus et in fugiat aliquid nostrum asperiores. Laboriosam vitae, minus odio! Iure id quaerat voluptatum.</p>
        <a href="#section-a" class="button">MAS INFORMACIÓN</a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  <section id="section-a">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
    <li><img src="prueba.png" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="prueba.png" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="prueba.png" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="prueba.png" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur error deserunt saepe explicabo obcaecati cupiditate dolor quam, nisi illo! Soluta.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="features">
      <div class="feature">
      <i class="fa fa-gear icon"></i>
      <div class="feature-contnt">
        <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="feature">
      <i class="fa fa-gear icon"></i>
      <div class="feature-contnt">
        <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- Features Two. -->
    <div class="features">
      <div class="feature">
      <i class="fa fa-gear icon"></i>
      <div class="feature-contnt">
        <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="feature">
      <i class="fa fa-gear icon"></i>
      <div class="feature-contnt">
        <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Slider. -->

<!-- Preguntas -->
  <section id="section-b">
  <div class="preguntas">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Preguntas frecuentes</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit laboriosam repellat labore, ad qui assumenda. Beatae perferendis at, provident aspernatur.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Preguntas 2 en flex -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="features-a">
    <div class="feature-a">
    <div class="feature-contnt2">
      <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="feature-a">
    <div class="feature-contnt2">
      <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

<!-- Preguntas 2-4 en flex -->
<div class="features-a">
  <div class="feature-a">
  <div class="feature-contnt2">
    <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="feature-a">
  <div class="feature-contnt2">
    <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Preguntas 4-6 en flex -->
<div class="features-a">
  <div class="feature-a">
  <div class="feature-contnt2">
    <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="feature-a">
  <div class="feature-contnt2">
    <h2>¿PORQUÉ ESCOJER PRFTA?</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, odit, earum! Veniam, repudiandae, ullam. Officia ut officiis voluptatem doloremque praesentium?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</div>

<!-- Curso -->
  <div class="clase">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>¿Listos para comenzar?</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium possimus officia, consequuntur repellat natus voluptatibus ad explicabo architecto! Quos, saepe!</p>
    <div class="botones">
    <a href="#section-a" class="btn">PRESENCIAL</a>
    <a href="#section-a" class="btn2">EN LINEA</a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: YES, that is what im looking for!

Comment: You took like 20 minutes to figure it out! What do I need to add and change to the css? Thank you! @Manish Maharjan